# Passing Multidimensional C Array to FORTRAN Function for Modification

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, fortran

I'm attempting to pass a multidimensional array, initialized in C, to a FORTRAN function and modify the array elements. I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17538937/passing-pointer-from-c-to-fortran-subroutine), but I've been unable to get it working with the multidimensional array. Attempting to write to the array results in a core dump. What am I missing?

Code example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

double f_function(double ****);

double ****alloc_4D_double(int wlen, int xlen, int ylen, int zlen)
{
    int i,j,k;

    double ****ary = (double****)malloc(wlen*sizeof(double***));

    for (i = 0; i < wlen; i++) 
    {
        ary[i] = (double***)malloc(xlen*sizeof(double**));

        for (j = 0; j < xlen; j++) 
        {
            ary[i][j] = (double**)malloc(ylen*sizeof(double*));

            for (k = 0; k < ylen; k++) 
            {
                ary[i][j][k] = (double*)malloc(zlen*sizeof(double));
            }
        }
    }

    return ary;
}

int main ( void ) {

    double ****cary = alloc_4D_double(2, 2, 2, 2);

    // intialize values
    for (j=0; j < 2; j++)
    {       
        for (k=0; k < 2; k++)
        {
            for (l=0; l < 2; l++)
            {
                for (m=0; m < 2; m++)
                {
                    cary[j][k][l][m] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }   

    f_function (cary);

    return 0;
}
```

and

```
    real(4) function f_function(cary)
        use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding    
        !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES C :: f_function

        implicit none    

        real(c_double)        , intent(out), dimension(2,2,2,2) :: cary

        ! attempt to overwrite value (core dump!)
        cary=1.1_c_double

        ...

    end function f_function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Fortran, multidimensional arrays are stored as contiguous data in memory.

However, you declare your multidimensional array in C by pointer to pointers to... Obviously Fortran don't know what to do with this.

You simply have to `malloc(wlen*xlen*ylen*zlen*sizeof(double))`, and pass this single pointer to your Fortran program.

If you badly need your multiple pointer representation, you can first allocate your data array as contiguous data with a single malloc, and then allocate your pointers to pointers, making them ultimately point inside the data array. And like previously, you pass to Fortran only the pointer to data array. Thus Fortran won't see the multiple pointers, but you will still be able to use them in C.

Comment: i think this will work. do you have an example of "and then allocate your pointers to pointers, making them ultimately point inside the data array"?

Comment: Simply replace `ary[i][j][k] = (double*)malloc(zlen*sizeof(double));` with `ary[i][j][k] = &data[zlen*(k + ylen*(j + xlen*i))];` in your code, where `data` is your "main" pointer.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the ISO_C_BINDING in Fortran and the intrinsic from the module `c_f_pointer`, which will associate a C pointer with a Fortran array.   There is an example in the gfortran manual under  "Mixed Language Programming".

Comment: But there is still the problem that, as is, data is scattered among many double***, not contiguous as in a single double*.

Comment: By C pointer, I meant a pointer, and not a pointer to a pointer to ..., as you already explained.