# Passing 4D C Array to FORTRAN Function

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, fortran

I'm attempting to pass a 4D array, initialized in C, to a FORTRAN function. Following the advise from a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18881139/passing-multidimensional-c-array-to-fortran-function-for-modification), I first allocate the data array as contiguous data with a single malloc, and then allocate pointers to pointers, making them ultimately point inside the data array. This method works for a 3D array. However, when I go to a 4D array I don't get the values expected in FORTRAN. Does something need to change when I malloc the memory for C arrays > 3 dimensions or is there a bug in the alloc_4D_double function?

Code Excerpt:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

double f_function(double ****);

double ****alloc_4D_double(int wlen, int xlen, int ylen, int zlen, double *ary)
{
    int i,j,k;

    double ****multiDary = (double****)malloc(wlen*sizeof(double***));

    for (i = 0; i < wlen; i++) 
    {
        multiDary[i] = (double***)malloc(xlen*sizeof(double**));

        for (j = 0; j < xlen; j++) 
        {
            multiDary[i][j] = (double**)malloc(ylen*sizeof(double*));

            for (k = 0; k < ylen; k++) 
            {
                multiDary[i][j][k] = (double*)malloc(zlen*sizeof(double));
            }
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < wlen; i++) 
    {                     
        for (j = 0; j < xlen; j++) 
        {
            for (k = 0; k < ylen; k++) 
            {
                multiDary[i][j][k] = &ary[zlen*(k + ylen*(j + xlen*i))];            
            }
        }
    }

    return multiDary;
}

int main ( void ) {

    // create contiguous memory
    double *data1D = (double*)malloc(2 * 4 * 10 * 10 * sizeof(double));

    // map memory locations to allow use of array syntax
    double ****exposure4D = alloc_4D_double(2, 4, 10, 10, exposure1D);

    // assign a value
    data[0][1][4][4] = 0.777;

    // pass the pointer to FORTRAN
    f_funtion(data1D)

    return 0;
}
```

and

```
integer(4) function f_function(data)  BIND(C)
    use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding    

    implicit none        
!
    real(C_DOUBLE)       , intent(in),      dimension(2,4,10,10) :: data

    // this value does not evaluate to 0.7777
    write(*,*), data(1,2,5,5) 

    // this value does evaluate to 0.7777
    write(*,*), data(1,1,9,2) 

end function f_function
```

Comment: Is the difference due to C using row-major and Fortran using column-major storage?  You might just have gotten lucky with the 3D array, perhaps because all the dimensions were the same.

Comment: That's very clever. It looks ok to me. Maybe @JonathanLeffler is right?

Comment: A little index arithmetic suggests that @JonathanLeffler is right, that element `[0,1,4,4]` in an indexed-from-0 row-major array corresponds to element `[1,1,9,2]` in an indexed-from-1 column-major array.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark any suggestions for a quick fix to this?

Comment: Yes, either (1) write a function to translate indices from 0-based row-major form into 1-based column-major form (careful but not difficult programming) and another function to do the inverse or (2) on the Fortran side of things, create the array with 0 lower bound in each dimension and work with a permutation of the matrix into the same shape as you have on the C side.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark do you know of an existing library that will do option 1? I need to translate for 3D, 4D, and 6D arrays.

Comment: No.  I've always understood index raveling and unraveling to be the sort of function that junior programmers write for themselves on day 2 of their first job.  One hint: transform indices from n-D to 1-D then from 1-D to m-D, see the Matlab documentation for `sub2ind` and `ind2sub` for function signatures.